# Using Android DownloadManager for downloading files on https server with self-signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, self-signed, download-manager

Is there a way to do that ?

I've a bunch of services that work well with HttpUrlConnection, but i cannot use the DownloadManager for getting some files from that server, it works only in http without ssl.
The application runs on API 17+

I would use DownloadManager for semplicity, but i have no idea how to do it.
I have to use HttpUrlConnection ?

Thank you

Comment: If is to download files like json or xml you need to used Retrofit Library.

Comment: I'll take a look at that library thank you, but files are Excel and Word and so on

Comment: In that case, you can forget Retrofit and you you can watch this library : https://github.com/koush/ion#download-a-file-with-a-progress-bar

Comment: very useful thank you, but it's a workaround :)